# Magento use models to store/transfer data

Tags: magento, model

Lets say I create a table object in magento  -

```
$model = Magento::getModel('table1')
$model->getCollection()->getFirstItem->setname('newname');
```

But I dont save it . I dont want to store it in db now.

Now I do

```
$model2 = Mage::getSingleton('table1')  
# It should return same table object.
$name = $model->getCollection()->getFirstItem->getname();
```

I dont get $name as newname, above line fires a sql and gets the name from DB, logically if I am getting same object from singleton then I should be able to retrieve the $name value as newname.

Answer (score 4):

The first request for your model uses `getModel`.  This retrieves an instance model.

The second request for your model users `getSingleton`.  This instantiates an instance model and registers it as a singleton.  From this point on, future requests to `getSingleton` or `getModel` will return the same object.  However, models instantiated with `getModel` prior to registers the model as a singleton will maintain their instance state.

"Works as Designed"

Comment: You mean If I use getsingleton for model(first line) , I should be able to retrieve $name value as newname.
$model = Mage::getSingleton('table1')
$model->getCollection()->getFirstItem->setname('newname');

$model2 = Mage::getSingleton('table1')
$name = $model->getCollection()->getFirstItem->getname();
but still $name doesnt give newname

Comment: I didn't understand most of your question, the only clear thing was you didn't understand how singletons work, and than you're not including the actual code your'e using which makes further troubleshooting impossible.